# Jasper Studio com Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaspersoft-studio

Estou tentando adicionar uma conexão no Jasper Studio via a opção "Hibernate Session" Adicionei os .jars do Hibernate, o Driver do MySQL e setei o arquivo hibernate.cfg.xml, mas mesmo assim, sempre tenho a acessão:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbteste
```

Tentei também a conexão via "EJBQL". Adicionei os .jars das bibliotecas e um .jar com o persistence.xml e minhas entidades, mas sempre recebo a exceção:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JPAUnit
```

Alguém tem alguma dica de como realizar essas conexões. Eu quero realiza-las para testar os relatórios com consultas HQL ou JPQL ao invés de usar o SQL.

Comment: Qual é a versão do driver do mysql que está usando?

Comment: A versão é a 5.1.35, mas já tentei com a 5.1.6 também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente consegui resolver. O que acontece é o seguinte, bug no Jasper Studio. Eu estava usando a versão 6.2.2 e com ela não teve jeito de fazer funcionar.

Então, instalei a versão 6.3.0 do Jasper Studio e deu certo. 
Mas tem alguns poréns, só consegui a conexão via "EJPQL", para JPA utilizando bibliotecas do EclipseLink:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Já com o Hibernate, tentando usar JPA, cada vez que eu mudava a versão das bibliotecas, gerava uma exceção diferente na tentativa de conexão. Então, acabou que não consegui com as libs do Hibernate. 
Mas, se usar a versão 6.0.1 do Jasper Studio, com as bibliotecas do Hibernate 3.3.2-GA funciona com "EJPQL" para JPA. Porém, tem que compilar o jar com as entidades na versão 1.6 do Java, na versão 1.8 e 1.7 não deu certo.

Por fim, não foi possivel de forma alguma, tanto trocando as versões das bibliotecas do Hibernate ou mesmo do Jasper Studio conseguir uma conexão via "Hibernate Session". Sempre rola o mesmo erro:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbteste
```

;D